# Identifying this road bike brand

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

Can someone help me identify this frame? It was given to me in Switzerland. My uncle and cousin bought it already painted grey. I noticed an engraved logo in the dropout, but it does not look like it is Cinelli.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you need the brand for anything in particular? E.g., to find out a type of some component or similar?

Comment: [Cyfac](https://www.cyfac.fr/)?  I could see that being an early aluminum frame built by a company like that, but I can't find a logo that matches.  Given the company's ownership history, though, multiple logos seem likely, and a 1980s or early 1990s logo might not be online anywhere.  Are there any other markings anywhere, such as on the head tube or bottom bracket shell?  And that could just be the logo for whoever forged the dropout...

Comment: agreed on it probably not being Cinelli, their fancy frames seem to incorporate their logo into the dropout itself. Don’t think it’s a Condor, either, per their ID guide https://www.condorcycles.com/pages/condor-vintage-frames-and-bicycles